# Routing For Web Application

Tags: php, routes

i tried to make Router for Web Application, but when i input /user it's not same with /user/ 
the source code is [Github - 140 Chars Router](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/140-chars-router)

anyone can explain and maybe give me a simple code that can explain this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That router is just a proof of concept and should not be used in the real world.

> Its NOT a good router at all, don't use it on a real application, its not exception handled either. I did it just for fun and to demonstrate the simplicity

As for why it does not work, it is because it sees `/user` and `/user/` as two different routes. You have to add two routes in order for the router to catch them both:

```
function route_user() { echo 'User route'; }
$router->a('/user', 'route_user');
$router->a('/user/', 'route_user');
```

The router is *very* basic. It just adds routes and then matches it against the current path. It does not do anything else.

Here is an expanded and annotated version of the router:

```
class Router
{
    // Collection of routes
    public $routes = [];

    // Add a path and its callback to the
    // collection of routes
    function add($route, callable $callback) {
        $this->routes[$route] = $callback;
    }

    // Looks at the current path and if it finds
    // it in the collection of routes then runs
    // the associated function
    function execute() {

        // The server path
        $serverVariables = $_SERVER;
        $serverKey = 'PATH_INFO';

        // Use / as the default route
        $path = '/';

        // If the server path is set then use it
        if (isset($serverVariables[$serverKey])) {
            $path = $serverVariables[$serverKey];
        }
        // Call the route
        // If the route does not exist then it will
        // result in a fatal error
        $this->routes[$path]();
    }
}
```

A slightly more usable version would be something like this:

```
class Router {
    public $routes = [];
    function add($route, callable $callback) {

        // Remove trailing slashes
        $route = rtrim($route, '/');
        if ($route === '') {
            $route = '/';
        }
        $this->routes[$route] = $callback;
    }
    function execute() {
        // Only call the route if it exists and is valid
        $path = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : '/';
        if (isset($this->routes[$path]) and is_callable($this->routes[$path])) {
            $this->routes[$path]();
        } else {
            die('Route not found');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i know that, the source code is very basic. but is CodeIgniter/laravel/etc has same problem like /user and /user/ as two different routes?. thanks for your answer

Comment: I don't know. Probably not. You should read their documentation.